# React Stepper with dynamic and responsive steps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a React stepper with MUI and I wanted to have it be dynamic depending on the data coming in and also to be able to add/remove steps within that dynamic section. I was not able to find any examples or posts on here regarding what I had in mind, and the docs for MUI's stepper don't go anywhere near touching dynamic/responsive steps like this. I've been able to get it pretty far (actually a bit surprised I got it as far as I have), but I'm stuck right at the end. I've set up a generic example on CSB (link below), with the stepper pulling in data objects, displaying them on the dynamic steps, and the add/remove functionality works for the step labels, but not for the content. This is where I can't figure it out, I set up the structure the same for the labels and content, and since is basically just pushing to/filtering out arrays, I'm not finding where the difference is. I figure I'd post it here before messing with it any further. Also, if anyone has any suggestions on how to clean it up, I'd be happy to hear those as well, I'm sure it is a bit messy and heavy handed in getting the job done.

Heres the main Stepper component:

```
const DynamicStepper = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const [copiedObjs, setCopiedObjs] = useState([]);
  const [copiedLabels, setCopiedLabels] = useState([]);
  const [middleContent, setMiddleContent] = useState([]);
  const [stepsContent, setStepsContent] = useState([])

  //Dialog actions
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  //Stepper actions
  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  }

  //Setting up dynamic labels (actual code involves conditional api calls)
useEffect(() => {
  if(data) {
    setCopiedObjs(data)
  }
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  if(copiedObjs.length) {
    let labeling = copiedObjs.map((i) => (
        i.title
    ))
    
    setCopiedLabels(labeling)
    }
}, [copiedObjs])


//Set labels for stepper
const initialLabels = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
const finalLabels = ["One from the End", "Final"]

const steps = initialLabels.concat(copiedLabels).concat(finalLabels)

//Set content for stepper
     //moved into useEffect
// function  getMiddleContent(){
//   const content = copiedObjs.map((obj, idx) => (
//   <StepDynamic key={idx} props={obj} />
// ))
//     setMiddleContent(content)
//   }

useEffect(() => {
  
    const content = copiedObjs.map((obj, idx) => (
    <StepDynamic key={idx} props={obj} />
  ))
      setMiddleContent(content)
    
}, [middleContent, copiedObjs])

useEffect(() => {
  //add/delete steps
function addStep(n = 1){
  let newSteps = [...copiedLabels];
  let newContent = [...middleContent];
  let newLabel = ["new obj"]
  
  newSteps.push(...newLabel);

  console.log("midContent pre push: ", middleContent)
  let content = [<StepDynamic key={Math.random()*3} props={null} />]
  
  newContent.push(...content)
  console.log("postPush, newContent: ", content)
  setCopiedLabels(newSteps)
  setMiddleContent(content)
  
}

function removeStep(idx){
  let newSteps = [...copiedLabels];
  let newContent = [...middleContent];
  
  let steps = newSteps.filter((item, i) => i !== idx);
  let content = newContent.filter((item, i) => i !== idx)

  setCopiedLabels(steps)
  setMiddleContent(content)
}


  const initialContent = [<StepOne key={1} />, <StepTwo key={2} />, <StepThree key={3} addStep={addStep} removeStep={removeStep} titles={copiedLabels} />]
const finalContent = [<StepPenUltimate key={4} />, <StepFinal key={5} />]

  const content = initialContent.concat(middleContent).concat(finalContent)
  setStepsContent(content)

}, [middleContent, copiedLabels])


function getStepsContent(stepIndex) {
  return stepsContent[stepIndex]
}
      //Moved this section into useEffect to see if I got better results, but responds the same as before
// //add/delete steps
// function addStep(n = 1){
//   let newSteps = [...copiedLabels];
//   let newContent = [...middleContent];
//   let newLabel = ["new obj"]
  
//   newSteps.push(...newLabel);

//   console.log("midContent pre push: ", middleContent)
//   let content = [<StepDynamic key={Math.random()*3} props={null} />]
  
//   newContent.push(...content)
//   console.log("postPush, newContent: ", content)
//   setCopiedLabels(newSteps)
//   setMiddleContent(content)
  
// }

// function removeStep(idx){
//   let newSteps = [...copiedLabels];
//   let newContent = [...middleContent];
  
//   let steps = newSteps.filter((item, i) => i !== idx);
//   let content = newContent.filter((item, i) => i !== idx)

//   setCopiedLabels(steps)
//   setMiddleContent(content)
// }


  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        New Stepper
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Stepper Guide</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText>
            Just some words of guidance
        </DialogContentText>
          <div>
            <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
              {steps && steps.map((label) => (
                <Step key={label}>
                  <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                </Step>
              ))}
              <br />
            </Stepper>
            <>
              {activeStep === steps.length ? (
                "Complete"
              ) : (
                <>
                  {getStepsContent(activeStep)}
                  <Button color='warning' onClick={handleBack}>
                    {activeStep === steps[0] ? "" : "Back"}  
                  </Button>
                  <Button color="primary" onClick={handleNext}>
                    {activeStep === steps.length ? "Submit" : "Next"}
                  </Button>
                </>
              )}
            </>
          </div>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button color="error" onClick={handleClose}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  )

}
```

And heres the CSB: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-cerf-tsrbci?file=/src/Stepper.js:463-5442

**UPDATE**
After playing around and a lot of console.logs I think I've figured out where the issue is, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. When adding/ removing a step, the functions are wrapped within the same useEffect as the logic to set the content for the steps. This was done to be able to provide the functions to the StepThree component where the adding/ removing takes place on the UI. However, it seems the state update and the logic setting the content are not on the same time cycle and so the content setting does not have access to the new updated state. I've tried breaking apart the useEffect into multiple and tried just writing separate functions, but because there is a lot of conditional state being utilized, and in order for the different pieces to correctly have access, as well as to avoid infinite re-render loops, I keep coming back to the same setup. The label setting works fine because the setting of the array for the labels happens outside the useEffect that compiles the conditional state.

If I'm wrong on my assessment please let me know, and if you have any ideas on how to better structure this, I'd love to hear it. I've looked at useReducer as a possible alternative, but I'm not that familiar with the react hooks beyond useState and useEffect, and so far haven't determined how to write out the reducer, again I keep coming back to needing to have the conditional pieces of state available at the right place in the code.

Comment: The `Stepper` file is empty in the CSB!

Comment: Strange... it loads up all fine when I follow the link, not sure what to say or do about it